# EditText multiline not expanding when soft input is open

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline

I have seen many answers on this topic, but none of them has solved my problem. My layout file looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="@color/lightGrey"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatAppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/chatToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/chatListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/sendMessageContainer"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:transcriptMode="normal">
        </ListView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sendMessageContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sendChatMessage"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendChatMessage"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/chatInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/sendChatMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want it to initially show 1 line, but expand to a max of 5 lines as text is entered. I cannot figure out why my `EditText` is not going into multiple lines. I have a feeling it's because it's being anchored to some view but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: So it seems with the above code, my `EditText` IS expanding to multiple lines, but NOT when the soft input is open. I open soft input, type 2 lines, the EditText shows one line with a vertical scroll. When I close the soft input, it expands to 2 lines. When I open soft input again, there are 2 lines. If I type in another line, it shows 2 lines with scroll. If I close, it expands to 3 lines. Why is it not expanding when the soft input is open?

Comment: Why have you specified `android:lines="1"` if you want it to be multi line?

Comment: Because I want it to initially show one line, but expand to a max of 5 lines.

Comment: From the documentation of `lines`: **Makes the TextView be exactly this many lines tall.** (http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lines) So in your case, set `inputType="textMultiLine"` and set `maxLines="5"` and remove `lines`.

Comment: I tried this, but it's initially showing 5 lines.

Comment: That's weird because I just tried and it shows single line initially and as I start pressing the enter key it expands till 5 lines and stops expanding in height and keeps on expanding internally.

Comment: Sorry, it's not showing 5 lines initially. It's showing one, but isn't expanding at all. Did you use the exact same layout?

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, this seems to be a different problem altogether. Please refer updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You have set lines to 1 that's why it's showing only one lines.

Change `android:lines="5"`

and add `android:minLines="1"`

It would be

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/chatInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: Please refer edit on the question, I want there to initially be one line but expand to a max of 5.

Comment: Removing `android:lines=1` causes there to initially be 5 lines.

Comment: @VedavyasBhat: Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, this seems to be a different problem altogether. Please refer updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
 android:lines="5"
```

then after its looks like

```
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextmessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="15"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_txt_size" />
```

Comment: Please refer edit on the question, I want there to initially be one line but expand to a max of 5.

Comment: you mean auto expand line??

Comment: @VedavyasBhat new updated answer works perfect for me. try to make height to wrap_content may be its.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, this seems to be a different problem altogether. Please refer updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
               <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/chatInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:minLines="5"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: Please refer edit on the question, I want there to initially be one line but expand to a max of 5.

Comment: Same problem. One line initially, doesn't expand.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, this seems to be a different problem altogether. Please refer updated question.

Comment: Remove android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Answer (score 0):

you can do this also:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="nasuakza.com.br.nasuakz.activities.AtvProduto">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/descricao" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This seems to be a different problem altogether. Please refer updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to your source code

```
editor.setSingleLine(false);
```